# Стриминг больших файлов в Django (xls, csv, xlsx)

Tags: python, django, xls, xlsx

На  проекте  есть экспорт данных в csv, xls, xlsx файлов. Использую стандартные библиотеки (csv, xlwt). Проблема заключаеться в том, что файл долго пишеться и сервер принудительно обрывает соединение, юзер не может скачать файл. Есть ли возможность стриминга для всех 3х типов файлов? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про это есть в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects):

```
def generate_large_response():
    with open('WarAndPeace.txt') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield line


def some_view(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(generate_large_response)
```

Но я сомневаюсь в том, что проблема именно в долгой **записи** файла. Скорее в долгом формировании электронной таблицы. А в этом случае `StreamingHttpResponse` вам не поможет. Нужно будет подключать в проект [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) и менять логику работы.